# Restangular put loses part of the url

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

I want to modify one object via a REST API using Restangular on the client side. I do the following:

```
Restangular.setBaseUrl('/api/v1');
return Restangular.one('lists', item.listId).one('items',item.order).get().then(function(elem) {
    elem.text = item.text;
    elem.put();
});
```

But the put method gets the wrong URL missing the ID for the last member (item.order).

The expected url is `/lists/2/items/22` but i get `/lists/2/items` and the PUT fails.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: is `order` null or something? (I know, stupid question)

Comment: No, order is 22 (for example). I think I'm not getting the way to do edits right.

Comment: Sure you should probably use `.put()` or `.save()` to edit. But the URL should be built correctly regardless of the verb you use.

Comment: Never used that library... how does `elem.put()` know wheat URI to PUT to? is it part of the `elem` object?

Comment: Yes, it stores the route on the object. In this case, the problem is that I lose part of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, let me try a theory :)

My comment above was a bit lame because I was focusing on the first part of the code and not the `put()`.

The first part is perfect, you tell Restangular to build the URL with `one()` methods and the GET request must be very fine.

Then, base on a new Restangular-aware object, you try to persist the change in your API.
However, I believe that Restangular does not actually know what field to use as id in order to build the right query for your `elem` object.

Did you try to configure, in your Restangular Entity Provider the fields property?

```
RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
   id: "orderId",
});
```

I believe that specifying the right field as **id** would suffice.

As a bonus, it seems that `.save()` will use PUT or POST accordingly if it's a new object or not.

Hope this helps

Comment: That was it. My entities had ids that weren't "id". Thanks.